# Advice on beginning self-learning physics from scratch

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

I am pursuing masters degree in computer applications. I have no formal Mathematics and Physics background but for masters degree entrance examination I have studied senior high school level Mathematics with some introductory college level Mathematics like multi-variable calculus, advance linear algebra etc but that was 2 years back.

In my personal opinion computer programming is a monotonous work which is making me bored and from past 2 years (after studying mathematics)and I have a strong urge to self learn Mathematics and Physics.

Maths is prerequisite for both computing especially advanced topics (Algorithms, Artificial Intelligence etc) and Physics so I have decided to cover these Mathematical topics first

**1.** Linear Algebra by using [Introduction to Linear Algebra from Gilbert Strang](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0980232716)

**2.** Trigonometry by using [Trigonometry by Charles P. McKeague and Mark D. Turner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1111826854)

**3.** Coordinate Geometry **(*Need Recommendation for book to cover this topic*)**

**4**. Calculus **(*Confused which book to use Thomas' Calculus or Stewart's or some other*)**

And finally [Fundamentals of Physics Extended by David Halliday, Robert Resnick and Jearl Walker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118230728) as my first physics book

It will take a lot of time to cover all this therefore I don't want to make any mistake in selecting wrong text for a newB. Can you help me by recommending some good books which i can use with or instead of books mentioned above and a suitable strategy to attain the goal in parallel with my regular studies.

Comment: I think that for AI and algorithms (Cormen level) discrete mathematics and combinatorics is important. I don't see the application of coordinate geometry in Physics. You should explain wall level of Physics do you need.

Comment: @jinawee Right now i have negligible knowledge of physics. I want to get adequate knowledge of basics physics first on that basis i will decide further course of the journey but right know concepts, theories and achievements in the fields of of astro and quantum physics (sources are news, television shows, internet) really amaze me

Comment: Maybe the Feynman lectures, 6 easy pieces.  To get you started in Physics.

Comment: I'd start with any introductory physics book, and get used to elementary Newtonian physics: F=ma and some elementary electromagnetism. Intro books are pretty much all the same, so it doesn't matter much which one you pick. Once you get bored with masses on inclined planes, the a good next step would be Taylor's Classical Mechanics and David Griffiths' Introduction to Electrodynamics.